# Get the different column names on two tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, metadata

I have two tables with almost identical column names :
Here's a sample table

[image]

I want to get the columns names highlighted in red.

Any idea?

Comment: what's your purpose of having two tables with identical column names?

Comment: Table 1 will be use for temporary storing of data for current transaction, data from table 1 wll be transferred to table 2 with additional data. Data from table 1 will be deleted to allow other transactions. if that makes sense. @d_unknown

Comment: Your answer doesnt too @Strawberry, but thanks anyway! got the answer below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema' AND 
      TABLE_NAME = 'table2' AND 
      COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (
         SELECT COLUMN_NAME
         FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
         WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema' AND 
               TABLE_NAME = 'table1');
```

The above query returns the column names of `table2` not present in `table1`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fc661/3)